# How to decode multiple-digit gamma codes and get the gap sequence?

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, coding-theory, information-retrieval

How to decode gamma code ($\gamma$ code):

```
1110001110101011111101101111011
```

and get the gap sequence?

Detailed information about Gamma codes ($\gamma$ codes) with brief example of decoding can be found [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/gamma-codes-1.html).

But in their example there is only case when gamma code ($\gamma$ code) consists of one digit only, how to deal with multiple digits binary string?